# Get the list of primary keys and corresponding table name

Tags: db2

In db2 how can I get the list of primary keys and corresponding table name for a particular db schema?

I have found some query to get the primary keys from a table like,

```
SELECT sc.name
FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS SC
WHERE SC.TBNAME = 'REGISTRATION'  
AND sc.identity ='N'
AND sc.tbcreator='schemaname'
AND sc.keyseq=1
```

Can I modify the same to get complete primary keys ,column name and table name form a schema?

Comment: What platform are you running DB2 on?  Are you looking for a list of columns in each table, or a list of the columns used in each table's primary key?  (there is a big difference)

Comment: I need the table name, primary key name and column name.

Comment: Assuming that `sc.identity` is a Boolean (essentially) column, why would you remove autogen/identity columns from the listing?  Most primary keys in tables are that exact column type.  Are you looking for natural (external id) primary keys, as opposed to surrogate (code, usually numeric) keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  tabschema, tabname, colname 
FROM 
  syscat.columns 
WHERE 
  keyseq IS NOT NULL AND 
  keyseq > 0 
ORDER BY 
  tabschema, tabname, keyseq
```

Comment: I will be accepting this answer. And one question remaining is Can't we get the primary key constraint name in DB2 along with column name?

Comment: Which platform?  [This blog entry](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0411melnyk/#constr) suggests there's another table with this info, but schema/table names are different than your question mentions, so the platform probably differs.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Thanks for the blog. I'm pretty new to `DB2`, I didn't get that `Which platform?`

Comment: for the foreign key contraints you can take a look at syscat.references

Comment: iSeries, LUW, z/OS.... essentially, what OS/machine are you running it on?  None of the deployments of the system have exactly the same features, so knowing this information can be crucial.

Comment: Using SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMS suggests the OP is looking at DB2 for z/OS code.  The answer above uses catalog info for LUW.